# What is the right way to install Canon PIXMA drivers on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: drivers, package-management, printing, canon, libraries

My printer is a **Canon PIXMA MG5350** and I am using **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**. Linux drivers for debian-based distros are available at Canon's website, but the package depends on **libtiff4**, which is no longer available in the repositories.

This seems to be a known problem, but I've read too many possible solutions. Some of them work for me, but what is *the right way* to do it?

1. **Modify the package**, so it does not depend on libtiff4.

   - I tried that and the installation somehow works, but **cifmg5300** returns an error, because it is unable to load **libtiff.so.4**.
2. **Symlink libtiff.so.4 to libtiff.so.5**.

   - Works, but this definitely is a dirty hack...
3. **Install an outdated version of libtiff4** from the 12.04 archive.

   - Is this even secure?
4. **Another option?**

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

Comment: Debian maintain these things so get libtiff4 from their repository https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libtiff4 and scroll down the page: you will likely want amd64? so then you can go ahead and use the install script from the Canon deb package to install the driver;